# Item menu title longer than DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-menu

I want to do this 
Write three points with the last of item  if the item title is longer than the DrawerLayout!

[[image: sée this image ][1]]
UPDATE
i solve thé problem by this answer
[Item menu title longer than DrawerLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019491/item-menu-title-longer-than-drawerlayout/54019674#54019674)
[image]

Comment: add marquee effect or set the max length to your text

Comment: How i can do this

Comment: Post your code of listView

Comment: Post your code of listView

Comment: This not listview ,it is juste menu with navigationview

Comment: okay... just post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add style with ellipsize and set it as theme to your NavigationView.

```
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

And in your xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:theme="@style/TextAppearance" />
```

Comment: This is menu item not textview

Answer (score 0):

i suggest marquee effect, i your cas i think you need to display all the text

```
 <TextView 
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
android:text="This is a test of marquee on the text view in android."
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
/>
```

Comment: This is menu item not textview